How to add enum field to my SwiftData model
I try to add an enum field to my model:
extension Item {
    enum Diet: String, CaseIterable, Codable {
        case herbivorous = "Herbivore"
        case carnivorous = "Carnivore"
        case omnivorous = "Omnivore"
    }
}

@Model
final class Item {
    var name: String = "New item"
    var createdAt: Date = Date()
    var diet: Diet = Diet.herbivorous // <-- new field
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

But I keep getting a runtime error:

Fatal error: Passed nil for a non-optional keypath \Item.diet

Making the field optional solves the problem, or making it a String type, but I'm trying to find out why this is not working. It looks like the diet field from:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftdata/defining-data-relationships-with-enumerations-and-model-classes. So my main question is: what am I doing wrong?
I'm new with SwiftData so if there is a nice way to debug this myself, let me know. The magic behind the scenes annoys me a lot but I haven't found a way to visualize my migrations or database state yet.
Steps to reproduce:

Create a new XCode project (macOS, SwiftUI, SwiftData)
Run the application, hit the plus button to add an object, stop the application
Add the Item.Diet extension and the diet field to the Item class
Run the application again


Please describe the steps necessary to reproduce the problem, starting from a new project. Show a [mre].

The migration is performed but only in the sense that the new field is added to the database table but no default value is written so all rows has NULL for this field. And this is what later on creates a crash when SwiftData tries to assign nil to a non-optional property. It looks like a lightweight migration isn't working in this scenario when it actually should.
A workaround here is to not declare the persisted property to be of type Diet but instead the raw value for the enum, String. Then we can declare this property as private and instead use a computed property of type Diet as the public one
private var dietRaw: Diet.RawValue = Diet.herbivorous.rawValue

var diet: Diet {
     get { .init(rawValue: dietRaw) ?? .herbivorous }
     set { dietRaw = newValue.rawValue }
}

init(name: String, diet: Diet = .herbivorous ) {
    self.name = name
    self.dietRaw = diet.rawValue
}


So you're saying this is a bug in SwiftData/XCode/macOS? It would be a quite big bug in a widely used framework right? If this is really the case I might consider ditching this stack, as it doesn't really feel well-maintained..

Or maybe it's intentional, as stuff would break if I remove an enum case and retrieve an item from the database that has that case. I'll just go with your solution now

I believe it’s a bug in SwiftData but I wouldn’t say that it’s a widely used framework yet since it’s quite new. If you removed a case from an enum it would of course require a custom migration to update the persisted data since it’s quite a major change (and you might also need to change a lot of your other swift code as well)
